# Making use of document.forms[0].elements['someid'].style.backgroundColor

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I set `document.forms[0].elements['someid'].style.backgroundColor="red"` in a form and submit it.

How can I get the value of "red", so that I can make use of it in another page to set the background-color of a td row?  When I submit the form, my intent is to send `$_POST['someid'].style.backgroundColor` to the next page with the color value.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have a `td` like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In that case, you'd want something like this:

```php
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td <?php if(!empty($_POST['someid'])) echo 'style="background-color:'.htmlentities($_POST['someid']).'"'; ?>></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If you want to style every td, you'd need to add code like this:

```php
if(!empty($_POST['someid'])){
    echo '<style>td{background-color:'.htmlentities($_POST['someid']).';}</style>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<style> ".$myobject." { background-color:".$_POST['someid']."; } </style>";
```